# How to clear "remember_token" in Firefox after I log out?(using flask.login)

Tags: firefox, cookies, flask, remember-me, flask-login

I am trying to get user to login using flask-login.

**Login code:**

```
def signin(self, email, password):
    user = None
    userLoggedIn = False

    private_key = self.get_private_key(email, password)
    if private_key:
        public_key = self.get_public_key(email, private_key)
        if public_key:
            user = userManager.findUser(email)
            if user:
                userManager.changeUserPassword(email, password)
                userManager.changeCloudAccessKeys(email, public_key, private_key)
            else:
                user = userManager.addUser(email, password, public_key, private_key, True)
                userLoggedIn = True

    if userLoggedIn:
        login_user(user, remember=False)
        userId = user.get_id()
        identity_changed.send(current_app._get_current_object(),identity=Identity(userId))
        return True
    return False
```

**Logout code:**

```
def signout(self):
    from flask import session
    logout_user()
    session.clear()
    identity_changed.send(current_app._get_current_object(),identity=AnonymousIdentity())
    self.remove_logged_user()
```

And I decorate the views with @login_required,so that user can do things only when they are logged in:

```
 @app.route("/do_things",methods=["GET"])
 @login_required
 def do_things():
    pass
```

In Chrome,everything worked well.If user didn't log in,then the views decorated by @login_required will not be accessed.

But in Firefox,after I logged out,I can still "do things".I check the Firefox cookie and find out that there is a "remember_token" in cookie session:

```
Response cookie:
session:1q2w3e4r...
httponly:true
path"/"

Request cookie:
remember_token:""username@gmail.com|8c5873f3748b8f5d18e9bd10cd5e9ee678a9a0a9e0a406fccce982825a7a57f167025341d102ee59cbecbfc20f5dae597ca66e92e5e4926f9aa64c6c244788b1""
session:1q2w3e4r...
```

I find out that Firefox saved my user email in remember_token and included it into the http requset.So that the views in flask still think I have logged in .

How can I clear the user information in Firefox after I do log out in flask?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the remember_token cookie by setting the cookie of the response with a expires date in the past, like the code below

```
        logout_user()
        session.clear()
        yesterday = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
        out = jsonify(success=True, message="success")
        out.set_cookie('remember_token', '', expires=yesterday)
```